# adobe air support different screen resolutions in android

Tags: android, air, screen-resolution

I need to develop application for Android with Adobe AIR. I have different sets of resources for different screen resolutions. So the question is:
How can I download appropriate resources for devices with different screen resolution? I have not finded this in Adobe AIR SDK for Android. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get screen size and resolution and after we know our screen size we can download 
appropriate resources. It is not automatically, we must code this feature.

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a47e0-8000.html#WS789ea67d3e73a8b23323219d123c9666630-7ffe

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/screens_virtual_desktop.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenDPI

Ignored settings:

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d1295d5cb8a4-7fff.html